# How to create a histogram or bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have checked out some of the answers related to my question.

Data:

```
nifty_returns = {2012:[27,0],2013:[6,-14],2014:[31,0],2015:[-4,-4],
                 2016:[3,-12], 2017:[28,0], 2018:[3,-5]}

bnf_returns = {2012:[56,0],2013:[-9,-28],2014:[64,-13],2015:[-10,-16],
                 2016:[7,-18], 2017:[40,0], 2018:[6,-8]}

strat_returns = 
{'2012': [105, -2], '2013': [99, -3], '2014': [56, -5], '2015': [457, -12], '2016': [113, 0], '2017': [84, 0], '2018': [164, 0]}
```

I want to plot the dates i.e. keys of the dictionaries above as the x-axis, the values(lets assume only the 1st in list) as bars next to each other corresponding to the same year.

I am getting confused whether I need a bar chart or histogram and how to go about it.

Really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean this? See [matplotlib grouped bar charts](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py)

```
labels = strat_returns.keys();
x = np.arange(len(xticks))
y0  = list(map(lambda x: x[0], nifty_returns.values()))
y1 = list(map(lambda x: x[0], bnf_returns.values()))
y2 = list(map(lambda x: x[0], strat_returns.values()))

width = 0.25  # the width of the bars
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x-width, y0, width, label='nifty_returns')
rects2 = ax.bar(x, y1, width, label='bnf_returns')
rects3 = ax.bar(x+width, y2, width, label='strat_returns')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels);
ax.legend()
plt.show();
```

[image]